# Set up an unsubscribe page on Cloud Pages landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

I'm trying to set up a custom unsubscribe page in MC's Cloud Pages.  There is a decent doc [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/smart_capture_advanced_procedures/creating_a_custom_unsubscription_page_using_smart_capture/) on how to use smart capture to create an unsub on a landing page.  However, this guide doesn't seem to apply to the new cloud pages landing pages.

I'm essentially trying to recreate the one click unsubscribe functionality of the default unsubscribe center in a cloud pages landing page, but I can't figure out how it's done.

Has anyone every done this?  If so, is there a guide somewhere I've missed?  Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Just thought I'd add a comment for anyone wondering why there are no responses to this ticket... it's probably because Salesforce/Marketing Cloud suggests you find an integration partner to facilitate this, to the tune of 5 figures.  If you are looking for any level of customization on the unsubscribe center (or profile center), even as simple as small text changes, don't expect this to be an easy process.  They have this locked down tight.

Comment: In my experience, custom preference centers are generally take about 30-50 hours to build.  One-click unsubscribe pages simply log an unsub event, which is documented several places -- here and in the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more information on how your company facilitates subscription preferences? Is the source of truth in the all subs list or is there a separate DE or publication list for unsubscribes?

It is fairly simple to create a standard data extension and then use smart capture to send submissions to that form.

If you are looking to get URL parameters for auto populating form fields or hidden form fields, that is not supported in smart capture. I have been successful in hacking together bits and pieces of smart capture code and my own code into a classic code view cloud page. Here is what I did:

1. Create a standard data extension with fields
2. Create cloud pages with content builder
3. Drag smart capture onto a content area
4. Select the data extension I am targeting
5. Drag a field onto the content area
6. Configure submit behavior
7. Publish the page

This is just to get the code from a working form - there is auto generated external javascript that appends form data to your submission so that the form handler can add data to the correct data extension.

You can now copy the source code from the published cloud page and paste it into a classic-pages code-view page. Once there, you can customize your form as much as you want and add as much of your own javascript as you want. Submissions from the modified form will be put into the same data extension.